# Pure (My)SQL transformations

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to promote the usage of a database versioning system (http://code.google.com/p/flyway/) on the project I'm currently working on - and to that end when we make changes to the database, we're propagating those changes through a series of deltas. It's still very early doors at the moment, so we've had the luxury of being able to make "destructive" deltas and re-populate the DB post-delta. 
We are nearing the point where we need to be able to restructure the DB with production data, and so I want to be able to ideally move data around the database within MySQL alone.

For example - I want to take the column contents of TABLE_1:the_value, create the column on TABLE_2 and then copy the values from TABLE_1 to TABLE_2 WHERE id_org and id_club match

```
TABLE 1
--------------------------------
| id_org | id_club | the_value |
--------------------------------
|   213  |    213  |    1      |
-------------------------------- 
|   214  |    213  |    2      |
-------------------------------- 
|   212  |    210  |    5      |
-------------------------------- 

-- intervening DDL that adds "the_value" to table 2
-- 2nd row on table 1 not copied across due to absence of matching id's

TABLE 2
--------------------------------------------
| id_org | id_club |    foo    | the_value |
--------------------------------------------
|   213  |    213  |     bar   |     1     |
--------------------------------------------
|   212  |    210  |     bar   |     5     |
--------------------------------------------
```

I've used the FOR EACH ROW construct with Triggers before, but cannot find documentation on the MySQL site that suggests or demonstrates how to use that to iterate over a result set in order to copy it to the target table. That may be more of a reflection of my inability to locate the appropriate information..

Can anyone offer me any pointers on this matter?

Comment: who said that doing set operations you need to do iterations? Set operations are best suited for sets :-). You need not to forget that when working with databases.

Comment: yup, I realise that (see below) - believe me, I have kicked myself in the butt several times in the last 24 hours...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming TABLE 2 already exists with id_org, id_club, and foo, just create the 'the_value' column and issue an UPDATE call using joins

See the [UPDATE manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)

```
UPDATE table1 t1, table2 t2 SET t2.the_value=t1.the_value 
WHERE t1.id_org = t2.id_org AND t1.id_club = t2.id_club
```

Comment: LOL - talk about hiding in plain sight - sometimes it's so obvious you can't see it, I forgot UPDATE would iterate like this, I'm so used to using it to target a single row. Thanks for answering my lame question...